# How to override nginx location setting in order to customize configuration for a specific case?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a Nginx location configuration to match with api request url as below

```
location ~ /api/(.*) {
         rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
         proxy_pass        http://localhost:8082;
         proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
}
```

Now I want to customize a specific url as `/api/webscraper/(.*)` to have a different proxy with port **8083**

```
location ~ /api/webscraper/(.*) {
         rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
         proxy_pass        http://localhost:8083;
         proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
}
```

I know that the later location url also match with former location pattern, hence when I request to `/api/webscraper/(.*)`, it's always forward to proxy with port **8082** rather than what i expect is **8083**.

*So how could I take precedence the later setting over the former one for this specific case*? I just think that the order of location settings may provide a kind of overriding but swapping location setting order didn't work for me.

Comment: Regular expression location blocks are evaluated in order. It definitely **will not work** if `webscraper` is placed last.

Comment: I tried to move it to top but wont work also :)

Comment: Make sure that you restart `nginx`. Test the configuration using `nginx -T` and ensure that the changes are being read by `nginx` within the correct `server` block. Clear the browser cache between tests. Enable the `rewrite_log` and look at the access log to understand what is happening.

Comment: Why not just get rid of regexps and it will become much easier